# How to TypeScript fetch

Tags: typescript

I just started to learn TypeScript and I'm trying to convert a utility file to TypeScript. I fixed most of the errors but I'm confused about the error I received from a `fetch` command.

```js
fetch(process.env.REACT_APP_API_URL)
```

This gives me the following error:

> TS2345: Argument of type 'string | undefined' is not assignable to parameter of type 'RequestInfo | URL'.  Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'RequestInfo | URL'.

What's confusing me is that I have another `fetch` somewhere else that isn't giving any errors:

```js
fetch(`https://somerandomapi.io/?token=${process.env.REACT_APP_API_TOKEN}`)
```

How do I fix the error here? When I search for `TS2345`, the issues don't seem that similar to me yet but that's probably because I'm still new to TypeScript.

### Update

When I updated my code to

```js
fetch(`${process.env.REACT_APP_API_URL}`)
```

The error went away. Although I feel like this is not the solution I should be doing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this help?

```
fetch(new URL(process.env.REACT_APP_API_URL!))
```

(Assuming that it is a URL from the name of the variable)

Comment: Also, by the error you get, it means that `process.env.REACT_APP_API_URL` has no defined value. Is this configured correctly?

Comment: Adding `!` at the end does get rid of the error but what does it do? And yes it is configured correctly. I have `.env.example` which has a blank value but the actual `.env` has the correct value.

Comment: `!` means that we are saying TS that the variable will definitely have a value and it is not undefined